# Is there any xml parsers that allow to add element by path in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, path

Is there any way to add to xml document a bunch of entries using "path" like this:

```
element = xmldoc.createElement("Work\\MainProject\\prj\\project.vcproj")
xmldoc.appendChild(element)
```

Which will automatically create all necessary entries in xml file?

Thanks a lot,
Roman

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for (it's a bit unclear what "all necessary entries" means). Anyway, here is how you can create two kinds of XML hierarchies based on a "path string" using ElementTree (tested with Python 2.6). Note: minidom is not really necessary; it is only used for pretty-printing.

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

def deep(tags):
    """Create a deep hierarchy with tags[0] as the root and
    tags[-1] as the sole leaf node"""
    root = Element(tags[0])
    parent = root
    for tag in tags[1:]:
        elem = SubElement(parent, tag)
        parent = elem
    return root

def shallow(tags):
    """Create a shallow hierarchy with tags[0] as the root and
    the other items as direct children"""
    root = Element(tags[0])
    for tag in tags[1:]:
        elem = SubElement(root, tag)
    return root

def pprint(s):
    dom = parseString(s)
    return dom.toprettyxml(indent=" ")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = "Work/MainProject/prj/project.vcproj"
    taglist = p.split("/")

    d = deep(taglist)
    print pprint(tostring(d))

    s = shallow(taglist)
    print pprint(tostring(s))
```

=>

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Work>
 <MainProject>
  <prj>
   <project.vcproj/>
  </prj>
 </MainProject>
</Work>

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Work>
 <MainProject/>
 <prj/>
 <project.vcproj/>
</Work>
```